# Oracle 12C peformance issue - waiting time increased drastically

Tags: oracle

Recently we upgraded oracled DB from 11G to 12C. During first week after upgrade we did not notice any performance issue. However, suddenly decrease in performance (not even gradual decrease) popped up. Here are the details observed. Request your guidance to debug the issue. Let me know if any details needed further

**1.** AWR report shows a sudden increase in wait time. Report was taken for 2 hours period

[image: AWR -Foreground Wait Event]

**2.** AWR  before problem:

[image: AWR -Foreground Wait Event]

Comment: We had similar problems, of which not few were created by Oracle 12c bugs, especially QUERY_REWRITE errors in our data warehouse. Do you have the latest patchsets installed? [This link](https://blogs.oracle.com/UPGRADE/entry/parameter_recommendations_for_oracle_database) was helpful, also the linked pages on the bottom of the page.

Comment: According to the AWR report, `latch free` wait event is taking most of the DB time. In order to get the problematic latch use the  queries given [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16240_01/doc/doc.102/e16282/oracle_database_help/oracle_database_wait_bottlenecks_latch_free_pct.html) and edit your question to add the result. Or go to the `Latch Statistics` section of AWR report to get the details.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions Lenniey and JSapkota. @Lenniey, Yes latest patches have been installed. Let me go through the links that  you guys provided.

Answer (score 1):

There are some known performance issues after upgrading to 12c that are related to the new optimizer features. Try the following to see if it corrects your issue. Note that this will turn off these features for now.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET OPTIMIZER_ADAPTIVE_FEATURES=false scope=both;
ALTER SYSTEM SET OPTIMIZER_DYNAMIC_SAMPLING=0 scope=both;
ALTER SYSTEM SET "_fix_control"='12914055:Off' scope=both;
```